# Ajax program syntax error

Tags: ajax, jquery

This Ajax program doesn't work. It has some syntax error which I am not able to figure out.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>    
<body>
<div class="click">Click me<div>
<div class="file"></div>    
<script>        
$(function(){    
    $(".click").click(function(){    
        $.ajax({    
            beforeSend: function(){
                $(".file").html(<img src="a.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> )
            },
            url: "a.txt",
            type: "POST",
            data: {             
                id :  0     
            },                  
            success: function(results){
                $(".file").html(results);
            }      
        });
    });
});    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

firebug throws an error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

$(".file").html("<img src="a.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">" )
```

Comment: this is not an ajax program...it is a javascript program...you just so happen to use the ajax functionality of a javascript library known as jquery

Comment: also why are you making a `post` request? It would be better if it were a `get` request instead. Since it is a .txt

Answer (score 3):

You had a syntax error in

```
$(".file").html('<img src="a.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> ')
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code:

```
$(".file").html(.....);
```

The contents inside the html tag should have single quotes like:

```
$(".file").html('<img src="a.gif" alt="Smiley face" ....');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing some quotes:

```
$(".file").html(<img src="a.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> )
                ^---here                                                  ^--here
```

You can **NOT** slap some bare html into a javascript code block and expect things to work. You're in a Javascript block - Javascsript syntax rules apply, meaning that the html has to be enclosed in quotes so it's treated as a string.

Answer (score 1):

syntax error in your code

Missing Quotes

```
$(".file").html('<img src="a.gif" alt="Smiley face" ....');
                ^                                       ^
```